# Double Click list box to Open Form to Specific record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list box that displays my entire Access databases records with a brief descriptions in additional columns.  The first column (0) has the record identifier (PART NUMBER) which is the primary key in the table.  I am trying to get the double click event to open the "SETUP SHEET DATA ENTRY" Form to the specific row in the list box.  The part number is classified as text and not numerical.  I don't know what the problem is and any advice would help.

List box name = Listallpart

Primary key in table name = PART NUMBER

Table name = Setup Sheet History

Form name = Setup Sheet Data Entry

```
Private Sub Listallpart_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "SETUP SHEET DATA ENTRY", , , "[PART NUMBER] = " & Me.Listallpart.Column(0).Value
End Sub
```

I have another question very similar....

```
Private Sub Listallpart_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strpn As String
Dim strco As String

strpn = Me.Listallpart.Column(0)
strco = Me.Listallpart.Column(1)

DoCmd.OpenForm "SETUP SHEET DATA ENTRY", , , ("[PART NUMBER] = '" & Me.Listallpart.Column(0) & "'" And "[CURRENTOPERATION] ='" & Me.Listallpart.Column(1) & "'")

End Sub
```

The code above is for another mod to the code.  Every record has these 2 required unique fields.  I am getting a "run time error "13" mismatch type".  I added the two variables in the beginning to make sure the values are correct.  I inserted break points and confirmed the values.  The data is numerical.

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949929/open-form-with-specific-record-from-a-listbox-click-event) appears to duplicate the change you made to this one.  Beware that one of these 2 questions may get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `[PART NUMBER]` is a text field, add quotes around the list box value in your `OpenForm` statement.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "SETUP SHEET DATA ENTRY", , , "[PART NUMBER] = '" & Me.Listallpart.Column(0).Value & "'"
```

Comment: Can you help me with the second question above also?  I thought it to be weird that I couldn't get it to work because it is so similar to the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Your second question is the inverse of your first question; seeing as [CURRENTOPERATION] is numeric you don't need to add the quotes to this in your `OpenForm`

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "SETUP SHEET DATA ENTRY", , , ("[PART NUMBER] = '" & Me.Listallpart.Column(0) & "'" And "[CURRENTOPERATION] =" & Me.Listallpart.Column(1))
```